# IMAP: best way to detect the presence of an attachment in a message

Tags: tcl, imap

I'm trying to write in Tcl/Tk a mail client using IMAP.
After connecting to a mailserver and selecting a folder, I retrieve the 'from:' 'to:' 'subject:' fields, but I'd like also to know if the email has an attachment or not. Following RFC3501, by querying BODY or BODYSTRUCTURE, it is possible to have the 'architecture' of an email. But deciphering the BODY/BODYSTRUCTURE is hard (for example, a simple HTML message with no images looks like a multipart message).

Is there a quick way to know if a message has an attachment ? Or what should I look for in the BODY/BODYSTRUCTURE to know if an attachment is present ?

Thanks in advance !
Luc

PS: By fetching the whole body (FETCH uid BODY[]) and using MIME I can extract an attachment. Here I'm looking for a way to know if there is an attachment WITHOUT fetching the whole body.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem with getting attachments or are you just lost in how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Parse the BODYSTRUCTURE and if test each bodypart. If its content-type is multipart, it's not an attachment. If its content-type is text, then you have to look at its content-disposition, which may be either `inline` or `attachment`. If it has another content-type, then it is an attachment.

[RFC3501 gives the following example](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-74):

```
     (("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "US-ASCII") NIL NIL "7BIT" 1152
     23)("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "US-ASCII" "NAME" "cc.diff")
     "<960723163407.20117h@cac.washington.edu>" "Compiler diff"
     "BASE64" 4554 73) "MIXED")
```

As you can see, there's a top-level multipart (the outer parens, "mixed"). That isn't an attachment since its type is "multipart". The multipart/mixed contains two parts, both with type "text" and nil content-disposition, so those two aren't attachments either.